# Excluding modules on SonarQube 4.3

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I'm trying to exclude modules of my eclipse project from sonarqube analysis. Starting of version 4.3, `sonar.skippedModules` is deprecated and I have to use -pl !skippedModule1,skippedModule2.

Ok, but my project is like this:

`-ParentProject
  -moduleA1
  -moduleA2
  -moduleA3
  -ParentProject2
     -moduleB1
     -moduleB2
     -...
     -moduleB100`

Ok, not 100 modules, but a lot. Is there another way to skip all modules below ParentProject2, instead of using `-pl !moduleB1,moduleB2,...,moduleB100`? Like, can I use wildcards (!moduleB*) or maybe add all of them to a property file or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution that I'm aware of to cover your use case.